# Convert Button action wont work on different profile

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

We created a convert button that will convert from one object to another.  It works on Administrator profile but wont work on other profile.  I enabled all APEX Classes Access and Visualforce Page Access but it still doesnt work.  Any work around you can think of?

Wont work = The button "OK" wont allow to convert.  There's 2 buttons.  the first button is the "Convert" button which will bring to another page to confirm that they want to convert.  the second button is "OK" and that wont work on any profile.  But Administrator does.

what I've done
 - redo the APEX
 - recreate the VF Page

APEX Controller

```
public class ControllerProposalConvertView {
public Id pId;
public String convertedAccountId;

public ControllerProposalConvertView(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
    pId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    System.Debug('#######leadId:' + pId);
}


public PageReference convert(){

    try{
    Proposal__c p = [SELECT Id, name, Already_Converted__c, Property__c, Square_Footage__c, Lot_Size__c, Lot__c, Cap_Rate__c, Term__c, NOI__c, Lease_Commencement_Date__c, Rent_Commencement_Date__c, Lease_Expiration_Date__c, Years_Remaining__c, Lease_Notes__c, Gross_Leasable_Area__c, Options__c, Original_Lease_Term__c, Suggested_List_Price__c, Broker_Relationship__c, Broker_Relationship2__c, Commission__c, Escrow_Fees__c, Existing_Debt_Retirement__c, Pre_Payment_Penalty__c, Title_Fees__c, Transfer_Tax__c FROM Proposal__c WHERE Id=:pId LIMIT 1];

    if (p.Already_Converted__c  =='Not Converted'){
    Listing__c c=new Listing__c(Name=p.Name, Property__c=p.Property__c, Square_Footage__c=p.Square_Footage__c,  Lot_Size__c=p.Lot_Size__c, Lot__c=p.Lot__c, Cap_Rate__c=p.Cap_Rate__c, Term__c=p.Term__c, NOI__c=p.NOI__c, Lease_Commencement_Date__c=p.Lease_Commencement_Date__c, Rent_Commencement_Date__c=p.Rent_Commencement_Date__c, Lease_Expiration_Date__c=p.Lease_Expiration_Date__c, Years_Remaining__c=p.Years_Remaining__c, Lease_Notes__c=p.Lease_Notes__c,Gross_Leasable_Area__c=p.Gross_Leasable_Area__c,Options__c=p.Options__c,Original_Lease_Term__c=p.Original_Lease_Term__c,Suggested_List_Price__c=p.Suggested_List_Price__c,Broker_Relationship__c=p.Broker_Relationship__c, Broker_Relationship2__c=p.Broker_Relationship2__c,Commission__c=p.Commission__c, Escrow_Fees__c=p.Escrow_Fees__c,Existing_Debt_Retirement__c=p.Existing_Debt_Retirement__c,Pre_Payment_Penalty__c=p.Pre_Payment_Penalty__c,Title_Fees__c=p.Title_Fees__c,Transfer_Tax__c=p.Transfer_Tax__c);

    System.Debug('#######c :' + c );
    insert c;
    p.Already_Converted__c='Converted';
   update p;
    convertedAccountId = c.Id;
    System.Debug('#######convertedAccountId :' + convertedAccountId );
    }

    else{
            String sServerName = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host');
    sServerName = 'https://'+sServerName+'/';
    PageReference retPage = new PageReference(sServerName + '/apex/ProposalConvertView2?id='+ pId); 
    retPage.setRedirect(true);
    System.Debug('#######ALREADYCONVERTED' );

    return retPage;
    }

    }

    catch(Exception e){
        System.Debug('#######Error  - Exception [' + e.getMessage() + ']');
        return null;
    }
    String sServerName = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host');
    sServerName = 'https://'+sServerName+'/';
    System.Debug('#######sServerName :' + sServerName );
    PageReference retPage = new PageReference(sServerName + convertedAccountId); 
    System.Debug('#######retPage :' + retPage );
    retPage.setRedirect(true);


    return retPage;
} 
public PageReference back(){
        String sServerName = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host');
    sServerName = 'https://'+sServerName+'/';
    System.Debug('#######sServerName :' + sServerName );
    PageReference retPage = new PageReference(sServerName + pId); 
    System.Debug('#######retPage :' + retPage );
    retPage.setRedirect(true);

    return retPage;
}      
}
```

VF PAGE1

```
<apex:page standardController="Proposal__c" extensions="ControllerProposalConvertView"> 
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="font-weight:bold"> You are about to convert this proposal to a listing. Are you sure you want to do this? </apex:outputPanel> 
<apex:form > <apex:commandButton action="{!convert}" value="OK" id="OK" rerender="hiddenBlock"/> 
<apex:commandButton action="{!back}" value="Cancel" id="Cancel" /> </apex:form> <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="font-weight:bold"></apex:outputPanel> 
</apex:page>
```

VF PAGE2

```
<apex:page standardController="Proposal__c" extensions="ControllerProposalConvertView"> 
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="font-weight:bold; color:red;"> This proposal has already been converted to a listing. Please click the button below to return to your proposal. </apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Define "won't work". Have you reviewed the debug logs?

Comment: What you mean by not working? Any errors or log statements? Have you enabled edit, create, etc. access on those objects for the other profiles?

Comment: Wont work = The button "OK" wont allow to convert.  There's 2 buttons.  the first button is the "Convert" button which will bring to another page to confirm that they want to convert.  the second button is "OK" and that wont work on any profile.  But Administrator does.

Comment: @highfive Yes I have enabled modify access on all objects.

Comment: @Eric I updated my body text.  but basically it doesnt continue to convert when I click on OK

Answer (score 0):

@Eric is correct.  I checked on the debug logs and missed one and fixed it from there....

ANSWER: Run the debug logs